# How to Develop CXF webService deploy on Wildfly 10.0 server in Eclipse-maven project

Tags: soap, cxf, wildfly-10

Apache CXF library (cxf-api-3.2.0.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: No idea what this text is. Is it an error message? A requirement? A homework assignment? A love letter?! Who can say - there's no question here, no context, in fact no useful information at all. You would have got a similar result by shouting it down a well. No-one can possibly help you, and it's hard to see how you imagined that they could. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you need some guidance on how to formulate a proper question - and therefore stand a chance of getting some useful assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly has it's own CXF integration therefore your deployment should not contain CXF libraries. If you want to use this, you'll have to disable Wildfly's CXF stuff as advised in the error message.